# Host key verification failed when building image with docker-compose from a private repo over ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, dockerpy

Inside my `docker-compose.yml` I'm using ssh address context to build a Docker image.

```
ui:
    build:
      context: git@my.git.host:ui/ui.git
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    container_name: ui
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    command: ember serve
```

Running `docker-compose build ui` gives me :

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build -> <generator object APIClient._stream_helper at 0x7faa8bc107d8>
ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: error fetching: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I build the image using docker build it works normally

`docker build git@my.git.host:ui/ui.git -f Dockerfile.prod`

My context

```
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.21.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.0.1
CPython version: 3.6.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

LATER EDIT:
I managed to reproduce the issue using the docker pip

```py
import docker
client = docker.APIClient()
log = client.build(path="git@my.git.host:ui/ui.git", dockerfile="Dockerfile.prod")
for chunk in log:
  print(loc)
```

Output:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("error fetching: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
: exit status 128")
```

Comment: I wish people wouldn't downvote questions without explaining why. So frustrating! Anyway, this is a known issue with docker-composer documented [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2856)

Comment: Found another open issue that details some more possible workarounds [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3038)

Comment: I've been successfully using the [workaround] (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3038) and inserted credentials in the url `https://username:token@my.git.host/username/repo.git`