# Docker compose considers the build context as a relative path instead of a URL

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, boot2docker

Docker compose consider the build context as a relative path, although it is in fact a GitLab URL.

**docker-compose.yml** (I use an access token for GitLab authentication)

```
version: '2'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
     context: PVNSE9czG66obizewyfQ@gitlab.mycompany.com:myproject/myservice.git#dev-1.0
```

**Error message**

```
build path /mnt/sda1/tmp/test-docker-compose/PVNSE9czG66obizewyfQ@gitlab.mycompany.com:myproject/myservice.git#dev-1.0 either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

I tried to put the context between " ", but it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen it,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454039/6310485
I think you are missing add colon like at end of your git URL 
e.g. https://gitlab.mycompany.com:myproject/myservice.git#:dev-1.0

Comment: I still have the same problem even with "PVNSE9czG66obizewyfQ@gitlab.mycompany.com:myproject/myservice.git".