# Vscode not detecting git folder after build - Docker

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and buidling a docker-compose file to setup my nodejs dev environment from a single file. Idea is to give a docker-compose file to a developer from where they can simply spin up the containers and start development.

When I `docker-compose up`, the application is built and runs with success. But my problem is when I open it in dev containers in Vscode, it fails to recognize as a git repo.

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.15.0 as develop-stage
WORKDIR /code
COPY package.json .
# Using package-lock file to fix the version of installed modules.
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 9608
CMD ['nodemon' 'index.js']
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    build: 
      context: 'https://username:token@bitbucket.org/abc/test-repo'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - my-data:/code
    command: nodemon index.js
    networks:
      - my-network
    expose:
      - 9608
    ports:
      - 9608:9608
    restart: on-failure
volumes:
  my-data:
    external: false
networks:
  my-network:
    external: false
```

Comment: When running `ls -a` inside the container on the root folder do you see a `.git` folder?

Comment: @brianangulo No

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file, and if so what does it contain?

Comment: @1615903 I have udpated my question with a dockerignore file.

Comment: What if you try to explicitly copy it: `COPY .git/ ./.git/`?

Comment: It says ` => CACHED [6/7] COPY . . 0.0s => ERROR [7/7] COPY .git . 0.0s ------ > [7/7] COPY .git .: ------ failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/.git" not found: not found`

Comment: Interesting - is your Dockerfile in the repository root?

Answer (score 1):

A [docker-compose context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#context-required) defines a [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/), which can use a [Git repository URL](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/#url-context)

> When the URL parameter points to the location of a Git repository, the repository acts as the build context.
> The builder recursively pulls the repository and its submodules. A shallow clone is performed and therefore pulls down just the latest commits, not the entire history.
>
> **A repository is first pulled into a temporary directory on your host. After that succeeds, the directory is sent to the daemon as the context**.

In other words, your context represent the content of the remote Git repository, it does not represent an actual (cloned) Git repository.

- The context is the set of files that are sent to the docker daemon for building an image.
- The source of the context can be a local directory or a git URL.

If you had to get a repository inside your image, your Dockerfile/docker-compose would *clone* the Git repository, not use a context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.git` folder is not within the root directory that's being copied over to the docker image. Depending on how your folder structure is set up it may be a folder or 2 above. You can find it by `cd .. && ls -a` until found. Then use an explicit `COPY ../.git .` to add it into the Docker image.

Comment: Couldnt find the git folder in the image. or maybe dockerfile copies "visible" folder ?

Comment: Updated my answer. I meant within your root directory before it gets copied over to the docker image. Your `.git` folder holds all of the `git` metadata so the goal is to find out where it is and `COPY` it into the image. Sometimes if you set up your folder as below so where is it?
`
app/
    .git/ <--- your git folder
    code/ <--- your app here
         package.json
         index.js
`