# Setting context in docker-compose file for a parent folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got a docker-compose file in which I want to set a context and docker file to look something like this:

```
build:
  context: <path to context>
  dockerfile: <path to dockerfile>
```

For now my file is in the root folder so its simply:

```
build: 
  context: .
  dockerfile: .
```

This way it does work.

The structure of the project is something like this:

```
./
  - folder1/
    - folder2/
         docker-compose.yaml
         DockerFile
```

I want to copy files as part of the commands in the DockerFile and I want the paths to be relative to the root folder of the project.

How with this project structure do I set the context to be the root folder of the project? I tried doing `context: ../../` but I then got an error:

> Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read (path): is a directory

How do I set the context correctly?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the actual Compose `build:` block you have?

Comment: @DavidMaze not sure if what i added is enough?

Comment: May 2022: See "[Build docker image using different directory contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084798/6309)": **Dockerfiles now support multiple build contexts**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've set:

```
 dockerfile: .
```

Just try to use a relative path to you Dockerfile from the set context:

```
context: ../../
dockerfile: ./folder1/folder2/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the context to be a parent folder, you can read it about it in the docker-compose documentation.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context

what you can do is have the composefile in the folder which in the the highest hierarchy and change the context accordingly. like so:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  srv2:
    build:
      dockerfile: src/services/srv2/Dockerfile
      context: ./
    image: srv2

  srv1:
    build:
      dockerfile: src/services/srv1/Dockerfile
      context: ./
    
    image: srv1
```

or you can make the context the directory of the service that contains the Dockerfile of the service

Comment: according to the answer the context must be at the current folder or lower, but the docker file can be wherever i want, meaning they don't have to be together at the same folder?

Comment: True, but it is important that they are under the same hierarchy @YonatanNir, in the example above, the compose file is in the same hierarchy as the src folder, the src folder has the services under it and the services have their Dockerfiles

Comment: And just another question. About the context - when i set it in the docker compose file, is it being set relative to the docker-compose file's location or is it set relative to the DockerFile's location?

Comment: relative to the docker-compose file. but the dockerfile still can't access the parent directory(for copying for instance). everything the service needs has to be inside the service's directory. or if you want you can use the higher context (compose context) and use files that are in the src folder, but then you will probably get files that are not needed when you are copying stuff in the Dockerfile itself. everything depends on your project structure and Dockerfile instructions so keep that in mind

Comment: So if I put the docker-compose in a parent folder from the DockerFile, the dockerfile will still not be able to copy from the location of the docker-compose? Because I thought it passes all the folder itself to a daemon and then can access it?

Comment: if you set the context as I did in the sample that I pasted then I think you can copy stuff from a folder in the same hierarchy or its predecessors as the docker-compose. I would just try and I see what works. it is faster than asking