# how to copy folders and subfolders in dockerfile outside build context

Tags: docker, dockerfile

how to copy folders and subfolders in dockerfile outside build context

```
Folder structure
Documents
--repo
  -- ab
   -- 1
   -- 2
   -- 3
  -- bc
   -- 5
   -- 6 
   -- 7
--pipleine
  -- dockerfile
```

I need to add folders(ab and bc and its subfolders) inside the dockerfile to build an image.

Docekrfile is

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt install sshpass
RUN mkdir -p /home/user
WORKDIR /home/user

# Install python requirements
RUN python -m pip install grpcio && python -m pip install grpcio-tools
RUN python -m pip install numpy==1.18.4 

ADD ab/* /home/user/ab/
ADD bc/* /home/user/bc/
```

And run docker build -f /home/user/Documents/pipeline/dockerfile -t new6 /home/user/Documents/repo

this will copy files not folders.

Comment: from which path are you running this command, your ADD command should use a working path from where your executiong this command.

This dockerfile should work properly if you run the build command from your `repo` folder

Comment: It seems like you've done the right things: the `repo` directory is the build context and you're copying the `ab` directory under that.  What's going wrong and how can you tell?

Comment: from the repo folder, if I execute the build command ADD/COPY it will copy files not folder structure. For eg: inside ab folders, I have 1,2,3 folders and inside bc I have 5,6,7 folders Inside these folders there are files. If I execute it will copy files in ab and bc folders but not 1,2,3,5,6,7 folders.

Comment: May 2022: See "[Build docker image using different directory contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084798/6309)": **Dockerfiles now support multiple build contexts**.